What is the Śruti status (Prāmāṇya) and dating of Mahopaniṣat? Is it accepted by sects other than Vaishnava-s?
The text seems to be of a much later date than mukhya and other old upaniṣads complied before common era (BCE) e.g.  Mahānārāyaṇa, Śvetāśvatara etc. as it is supposedly the conversation between Śuka and his father Vyāsa.

The text exists in two versions, one attached to the Atharvaveda in some anthologies, and another attached to the Sāmaveda. The longer version of the text, which is attached to Sāmaveda, includes the shorter version as first part and then presents more text.The date or author of Mahā Upaniṣad is unknown, but Deussen considers it to be the most ancient of Vaishnava Upanishads attached to the Atharvaveda.


The popular phrase "Vasudhaiva Kutumbakam" is taken from the Maha upanishad.

Yes. I know this. But with two versions (and interpolations?) of the text the question is about its status as a Śruti.

Two versions are present even for Brihadaranyaka, Mahanarayana upanishads. Having two versions, by itself, is inconclusive, I think.

Date of earliest commentary might indicate something

I normally assume this is a genuine upanishad, going by how famous the saying "Vasudhaiva Kutumbakam" is. Of course, my reasoning relies on conjecture. :)
